# PHP set Cookie - JavaScript read Cookie

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, localhost, webserver

I am developing a game.

I need to exchange data between PHP and JavaScript.

- PHP generates a value (a secret text), which is the solution of the
  game.
- PHP encodes the value via base64_encode(), enduser should not find
  the solution (easily).
- PHP stores the encoded value in Cookie.
- JavaScript reads the cookie value.
- JavaScript decodes the value, window.atob()
- JavaScript checks user entry vs. generated secret text from the cookie.

**This approach works on localhost, but not on web server.**

Following is the code I am using.
(in PHP, setting "domain" param with my website such "mydomain.com" did not solve the issue)

**PHP**

```
    function setMyCookie($name, $value) {
       setcookie($name, $value, [
           'expires' => time() + 86400,
           'path' => '/',
           'domain' => '',
           'secure' => true,
           'httponly' => false,
           'samesite' => 'None',
        ]);
    }
```

**JavaScript**

```
  function getCookie(cname) {
        let name = cname + "=";
        let decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
        let ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
        for(let i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
          let c = ca[i];
          while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
          }
          if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
          }        
        }
        return "";  
    }
```

**Question 1**:
How can fix my issue on webserver?

**Question 2**:
Is there another approach (other than cookie) which you may recommend?

Thanks
BM

Comment: base64 is not encryption, it's very easy to inspect cookies and base64 decode is a single line console command.  Have the client sent the proposed solution to the server (POST), which then verifies that it's correct

Comment: I think this would be a good use for an api, if the client doesn't need to have the answer to try and make an attempt. i.e., user makes attempt, js checks with php api and receives whether or not the solution is good.

Comment: Is the origin (domain and port)  of the php the same as on the javascript? Do you have console errors?

Comment: # async await: I do not want that the website is loaded by submitting on php

Comment: # plungjan: yes I checks every time, no console error.

Comment: #Tibrogargan: I know base64 is not the best, for the timebeing it is ok. Wht would you suggest to use cryption, php (crypt), javascript (de-crypt) –

Comment: You don't need to encrypt the answer sent by the client at all, the client already knows what it is.  Use TLS.  If you do need to have an authenticated response, sign or encrypt it using the server's public key.  Include the session token in the message to create an individualized response.  Private key encryption by a JavaScript client is inherently unsafe.